# Convert local time to UTC -8 (javascript)

Tags: javascript, datetime

I've seen lots of questions around on how to convert from local to UTC string, but i'm in need of something "deeper".

I need to have my date object (`new Date()`) converted to UTC -8.

The problem here is that i could probably use `setHours` after using `Date.UTC`, but that would totally break when, for example, the user is on UTC -8.

I've tried looking at moment, but i'm not seeing anything that could help.

Any tips?

Update: Explanation on why i need this ->
I'm making a REST API call to a SharePoint site which is set to UTC -8. The API does not calculate what i'm sending it so if i send it a datetime object with lets say April 19 2019 it will actually set April 18 2019 (because it is setting it as 12 A.M. and the time difference messes it up).

I have people from different timezones that will be using that app which is why i need something that doesnt setHours based on local time.

Comment: Don't get your question. Do you have an example? What do you expect? What have you already? What should fail when I'm on UTC-8 ?

Comment: I think you need to explain what exactly you are doing and what the issue is.

Comment: i've updated my question, hopefully this clears things up.